# Proposal to clarify "on-topic" help page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, help-center, wording

The [on-topic help page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Code Review is already fairly clear, but I would edit the following bullet point to make it clearer:

> - Best practices and design pattern usage

With the current phrasing, one could misunderstand that questions about general best practices in an abstract situation are considered on-topic (as it happened to me).

I would change it to something along the lines of "*Application of best practices and design pattern usage to your specific project*".

Sure, it is true that the line above,

> If you have a **working piece of code** from your project and are looking for **open-ended** feedback in the following areas:

implicitly implies that the question should refer to a specific, concrete project, with working code. But I believe that the small gain in clarity is worth the redundancy.

Comment: Bullet point lists draw attention. I can imagine users to skip the "working piece of code" paragraph entirely and jump to "Best practices and design pattern usage", without even reading the first paragraph. Your new line would definitely help to  mitigate that issue.

Comment: @Zeta I must admit that's exactly what happened to me :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree. That small change in wording will make a significant difference, but the part about "for your specific project" makes it a little unclear. I would recommend the change...

From:

- Best practices and design pattern usage

To:

- Application of best practices and design patterns

Comment: And now that I look, `Security issues` can be similarly misinterpreted, should be `Potential security issues`, or something.